# Why doesn't exec() work after chroot()?

Tags: c++, c, linux, exec

I was playing around with `exec`-family functions and I've seen a really strange behavior: they don't seem to work after `chroot()` system call.

Here's a relevant Quote from manpages:

> Special semantics for execlp() and execvp()
>
> The execlp(), execvp(), and execvpe() functions duplicate the actions of
>      the shell in searching for an executable file if the specified  filename
>      does  not  contain  a  slash  (/)  character.  The file is sought in the
>      colon-separated list of directory pathnames specified in the PATH  envi‐
>      ronment  variable.   If  this  variable  isn't  defined,  the  path list
>      defaults to the **current directory** followed by the  list  of  directories
>      returned  by confstr(_CS_PATH).  (This confstr(3) call typically returns
>      the value "/bin:/usr/bin".)
>
> **If the specified filename includes  a  slash  character,  then  PATH  is
>        ignored, and the file at the specified pathname is executed.**

That was the theory, now let's see how it behaves:

- I have `prog.c` file that will be executed by `execlp`:

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>

  int main()
  {
      puts("works!");
      return 0;
  }
  ```
- And I have `exec.c` file which will attempt to execute `prog`:

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <unistd.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <errno.h>
  #include <dirent.h>

  int main(int argc, char* const argv[])
  {
      const char path[] = "/home/zaffy/cool";

      if (argc < 2)
          return 1;

      if (argc > 2 && (chdir(path) || chroot(path)))
      {
          printf("Cannot chroot(%s): %s\n", path, strerror(errno));
          return 1;
      }

      /* Clear our environment, including PATH */
      clearenv();

      if (execlp(argv[1], argv[1], NULL))
      {
          printf("Cannot execlp(%s): %s\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));

          /* Well, we failed... let's see
             contents of the current root */
          struct dirent* entry;
          DIR* dir = opendir("/");
          while ( (entry = readdir(dir)) )
              printf("%s\n", entry->d_name);
          closedir(dir);
      }

      return 0;
  }
  ```

- all tests are done in `/home/zaffy/cool`:

  ```
  /home/zaffy/cool
  ├── exec
  ├── exec.c
  ├── prog
  └── prog.c
  ```

#### Test One: exec without call to chroot:

```
# /home/zaffy/cool/exec /home/zaffy/cool/prog
works!
```

#### Test Two: exec with call to chroot:

```
# /home/zaffy/cool/exec /prog 1
Cannot execlp(/prog): No such file or directory
.
..
prog.c
prog
exec.c
exec
```

I'm confused! According to man-pages, if I have passed absolute path to `execlp` it should not search in `PATH`, or if the `PATH` is not set, it should be set also to the current directory so I'm not able to see the problem here.

The file surely exists and is available! Even if I use `fopen` right before `execlp`, the `fopen` finds and opens the file, but `execlp` still emits the error No such file or directory.

Do you have any idea why this happens ? Why doesn't exec() work after chroot() ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is most likely that the program you're trying to exec is dynamic linked, and the dynamic linker is not present in `/lib` in the chroot environment. That would cause the `ENOENT` (`No such file or directory`) error. However just adding it by itself won't help. You'd need all the other files the dynamic-linked program depends on, including shared libraries and any essential configuration/table/etc. files these libraries need.