# Linux - Cannot execute binary file

Tags: linux, elf

I know this question has been asked a lot, but the problem remains fo me:

I have a 64bits ELF executable that I am trying to run on my Kali VM, but it keeps telling me that the file doesn't exist.

The solution most of the time for this problem is the difference of architecture, but my Kali is x86-64:

```
$ uname -m
  x86_64
```

like the file (named '8') that I am trying to execute:

```
file 8
8: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.27, BuildID[sha1]=0xf3b096c69086131b091d1805894fde4fae0537a0, stripped
```

EDIT: Error:

```
 $ chmod +x 8
 $ ./8
 bash: ./8: No such file or directory
```

EDIT 2 : lld:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffe37fe000)
libssl.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f680fac8000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f680f73c000)
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f680f343000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f680f13f000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f680ef28000)
/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f680fd49000)
```

I tried to install the 32 bits library to be sure, but it didn't solve anything neither. I also tried it on my Ubuntu, same issues.

Has anybody an idea on ho to run it ? Here is a link to it if some of you want to try on other architectures: https://www.dropbox.com/s/s3ucka4ufd00zmy/8?dl=0

Comment: Copy and paste the exact error message.

Comment: Done - 
I don't understand why people downvotes question so quickly...

Comment: How about the output of running `ldd` against it?

Comment: Done too - I dind't know this command

Comment: Does `ls .` work correctly in that directory? We don't need the actual output, just success/failure.

Comment: Yes it works, and gives me all my file, including this one

Comment: Is that file readable as well as executable?  `ls -l 8` should show something like `r-x------`.  If not, you should `chmod +rx 8`.

Comment: Yes it is:  `-rwxr-xr-x 1 Stan Stan 6896 Jan  1 15:37 8`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't exec() work after chroot()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342758/why-doesnt-exec-work-after-chroot)

Comment: You need to provide exactly all steps from opening console to the executing as I believe you it something else. Additionaly , execute "uname -a" and let us know about your distro

Comment: Okay, there you go, from the opening to the execution: http://pastebin.com/8FZ0fe95

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> bash: ./8: No such file or directory

This is caused by the file having an *elf interpreter* which is not installed on your system.

You can find out which elf interpreter your file is compiled with by running

```
readelf -l ./8 | grep interpreter
```

I am guessing that you have `/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` compiled in, whereas the *standard* 64-bit elf interpreter is `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`.

The best fix is to correct the build script for your executable (it has something like `-Wl,--dynamic-linker=/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` in it).

Alternatively, creating a symlink:

```
sudo ln -s /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /lib
```

will also fix the problem.

Comment: I tried `sudo ln -s /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 lib` but it didn't work for me. Any other thoughts? I have the same problem as with the first guy asking the question.

Comment: @warfreak92 Your problem may look very similar, but may be subtly different. You should ask a separate question, and provide your exact details.

Comment: alright, @Employed Russian, I opened another question here: https://superuser.com/questions/1266195/change-file-permissions-in-kali-linux